# Using multiple compound adjectives in single sentence

Tags: compound-adjectives

Can one use multiple compound adjectives in a single sentence? Example:

> Packed with energy-rich power, these batteries are specially formulated for power-hungry, high-drain devices.

Comment: The question you are asking is related to style and taste rather than to grammar or usage.  Personally, I think compounds can be over-used, but I suspect that my opinion is becoming out of date, especially in writing about science and technology, where you are constantly having to find words for new things.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but the phrase "energy-rich power" sounds a bit redundant to me.